# Applying Cloudant Search Index Query with no limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudant

Results from search index queries limited to 200 rows while sending limit as parameter, whereas if we set no limit param it only gets 25 result set.

How can I get the search index queries with no limit and getting result set for all possible count?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get unlimited results returned, but all query responses include a bookmark value. Make the same query with that value appended to the query (e.g. ...&bookmark=asdjfskdfskfj) and you will get the next group of results.